# One to many relationship behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a behavior about the one to many relationship that I don't get and it definitely turns me nuts.

Here is model 1:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, :autosave => true
  validates :organization, :presence => true
end
```

Here is model 2:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts, :autosave => true
  validates :accounts, :presence => true
end
```

Now, in a rails console:

```
>> acc = Account.new
>> org = Organization.new
>> org.accounts << acc

>> org.accounts
[#<Account id: nil, organization_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]

>> acc.organization
nil
```

or the other way around:

```
>> acc = Account.new
>> org = Organization.new
>> acc.organization = org

>> acc.organization
#<Organization id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

>> organization.accounts
[]
```

Is this normal behavior? Should I manually update both sides of the relationship?!

Comment: try to save acc.save and check

Comment: I don't want saving the object, that would trigger many other events that should not happen at that point. :)

Answer (score 1):

the answer is simple just save the object first

```
acc = Account.new
org = Organization.new 
acc.organization = org
acc.save
```

Answer (score 1):

Ref [`this`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) use `build`

```
org = Organization.new
acc = org.build_account.new
org.save
```

Comment: Well, 
    >> org = Organization.new
    #<Organization id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
    >> acc = org.accounts.build()
    #<Account id: nil, organization_id: nil, type: nil, created_at:     nil, updated_at: nil>

    >> acc
    #<Account id: nil, name: "Main", country_id: nil, currency_id:     nil, organization_id: nil, type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at:     nil>

    >> acc.organization
    nil

Comment: Ok formatting sucks but what it means it that until you save the org you get no bidirectional link still. Then I don't get why using this instead of just save.

Comment: Ok I get it. This won't work until org is saved. So if you have 2 in-memory objects, you have to assign the link both ways.